# Audio export settings used by QuickTime Player on OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, audio, quicktime, osx-mavericks, aac

Can someone please post, *in as much detail as possible*, which AAC audio profile and bitrate settings Quicktime utilizes during an export on OS X Mavericks (10.9) when choosing File > Export > Audio Only... using a 16-bit 44100 Hz .wav file as a reference

I can observe, using the Inspector window in QuickTime, that the exported files approximate 256kbps (VBR?) and are 48000 Hz, but I want more precise and complete information.

Comment: Can you supply a sample? By QuickTime X you mean version 10? (Disclaimer, I don't run Mavericks yet.)

Comment: @slhck I do mean version 10. I'm sorry for the confusion. I have removed that Roman numeral reference from the question.

Answer (score 0):

The default bit rate mode in QuickTime has been ABR for a long time.

> ### Average Bit Rate (ABR) - Default Mode
>
> `-- Recommended for controlling file size --`
>
> A target bit rate is achieved over a long-term average (typically
>   after the first few seconds of encoding). Unlike CBR mode, this mode
>   does not provide constant delay when using constant bit rate
>   transmission, but this mode provides almost best global quality while
>   still being able to strictly control the resulting file size.

This, and more mathematical information can be found in [Technical Note TN2271 -- Bit Rate Control Modes for AAC Encoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2271/_index.html).

Note that if you want control, you can use iTunes to set VBR/ABR, bitrate and HE-AAC.